# Which countries recommend Covid vaccine for pregnant women?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

It is still controversial if pregnant women should generally be vaccinated against Covid.

As far as I understood, the US-american and English authorities recommend vaccination, while the Germans do not (at least not in general).

Which major countries do recommend vaccination for pregnant women and which do not?

EDIT: There is the map https://hub.jhu.edu/2021/06/28/tracker-map-of-vaccine-policies-for-pregnant-women/ which was kindly provided to me by Chris Rogers, but unfortunately, it is from June and a lot has changed since.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. A quick Google search provided an answer at the top of the list for me. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Oh, I'm sorry, I probably used the wrong search terms. If you could be so kind to share the link you found with me?

Comment: No problem. Try https://hub.jhu.edu/2021/06/28/tracker-map-of-vaccine-policies-for-pregnant-women/ If this doesn't help, maybe you could [edit] your question to say why it doesn't 